# Using python class variables as dict key is good practice?

Tags: python, dictionary, peewee, class-variables

I wonder if i use class variables as keys in a dictionary can it be considered as good practice?
For example, this is object model in peewee.

```
class Abc:
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()
```

then i declare a configuration dict for it like this

```
conf = {Abc.name: Config(listable=False, format_on_edit=True), Abc.age: Config()}
```

I don't want to use string like `name`, `age` as dict keys because i'm afraid of mistyping, and want to make sure that Object/ Model field is valid.

I see Sqlalchemy or Peewee are using condition like `where(Abc.name=='abc')` or `filter(User.age == 25)` , not `where('name', 'abc')` like many other orms from Go or PHP since they don't have class variables.

It's quite good for prevent mistyping.
I've tried `hash(Abc.name)` and it works then class variables **are immutable for using as dict keys or not**?

Comment: Have you heard about `https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html` ? Also is this django ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i'm using enum on other context, but this is about model fields, many fields are defined in one model object and they aren't ENUM type, and the configuration dict is for model object. It's useless if i re-declare them (field name) as ENUM type. And this is not django

Comment: "Then class variables are immutable for using as dict keys or not?" What are you asking? note, you aren't using class *variables* as keys, variables cannot be keys, objects are keys, and you are using the objects referenced by your class variables *the moment you create the dict* as keys. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, then you haven't answer the question?

Comment: I am not understanding exactly what you are asking

Comment: I don't think using `Abc.name` as a key is doing what you think it is doing which is what I believe juanpa was pointing out.

Comment: Can you provide more context around how you are using this? I would say it doesn't look very pythonic and you have to be careful using this with [class instances](https://repl.it/repls/HugeDarkorangeDisassembly)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse The question is obvious, i want to create a dict to declare configuration for a model object, then i want to use model class variables instead of string

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse i've read your example code, but in Peewee, object field are declared at init and it would never be changed again. It uses `where(Abc.name==25)` , if you change the variable type, it causes error for the whole package too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may safely use them. Peewee replaces the field instances you declare as model attributes with special Descriptor objects (which then expose the underlying field instance, which is hashable).

For instance, when performing an insert or update, you can specify the data using the fields as keys:

```
User.insert({User.username: 'charlie'}).execute()
```